# Error pops up at structs and double pointers in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CHARS 10
char **readText(void) ;
typedef struct text_t
{
    char * * mt;
    int words;
}
Text_t;
int main(void)
{

    int i, words;
    Text_t.mt = readText();
    for (i=0; i<words; i++)
        printf("%s\n", Text_t.mt[i]);
    return 0;
}

char **readText(void)
{
    *Text_t.mt = NULL;
    char *word;
    *words = 0;
    while (scanf("%s", word=malloc(CHARS*sizeof(char))),
            strcmp(word,"END"))
    {
        (*words) ++;
        Text_t.mt = realloc(mytext, (*words)*sizeof(char *));

        Text_t.mt[*words-1] = word;
    }
    free(word);
    return Text_t.mt;
}
```

The goal of this programm is to take some words as input from the user untill the word "END" is entered. Then we print the given words with the same order as they were entered. The problem is when I try to run the programm, this error comes up:

```
main.c|16|error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token|
```

Comment: `Text_t`  is not an instance, it's a type (that you `typedef`ined) and  `words` is undefined so `*words = 0;` can't work either.

Comment: Its funny, how you can make C look like write-only regular expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
   Text_t tt;
   tt.mt = NULL;
```

ie

- create an instance ot the Text_t struct
- set its 'mt' pointer to NULL

whether thats the correct thing for your main aim I cant say, but at least it will get you past your current compile error